# plz any guide me for coq extension in VS code

Tags: coq

I am currently exploring Coq development in Visual Studio Code and would like to enhance my experience with suitable extensions. Could you kindly recommend all available Coq extensions for Visual Studio Code

Comment: VsCoq is the first link when I search for "vscode coq". I did not downvote personally (I feel like -2 is enough), but the question seems very low effort to me. Were you aware of its existence? Then mentioning you're looking for alternatives would surely make the question better, at least according to me

Answer (score 0):

The recommanded extension is [VsCoq](https://github.com/coq-community/vscoq).